# Nexus 7 boot loop

Tags: nexus-7, boot-loop

I'm not certain if this is the same as the other two questions about boot loop on the nexus 7,  but I have a nexus 7 that goes into a boot loop. It boots to the point of the unlock screen, then it sits there unresponsive for a couple of seconds before rebooting. I'm running 4.2, and the bootloader is locked. Is there anything I can try short of unlocking the bootloader and losing everything (or RMA)?

Comment: What was the last app you installed? What was it you performed on it last to produce the first boot-loop? Maybe try going into recovery and clear the cache?

Comment: Adding to t0mm13b's hint: You could try booting to "safe mode" and remove whatever you installed last (between the time a boot worked and before it started boot-looping).

Comment: @Izzy - how do I boot into safe mode?

Comment: Long-press power button, then *long-press* shutdown. This should offer you to boot into safe mode on JB. But as you probably cannot get that far (as this requires the device to already *have* booted), there might be some key-codes to achieve this -- they are mostly device-specific. Maybe another Nexus-7 user can help you out there, I don't know the key-combination.

Comment: I had the same issue...called Nexus support and they couldn't get me out of the boot loop. I believe I was running 4.3. I was instructed to clear the cache and then reboot. Did not work. Finally I had to restore to factory conditions before I was able to boot up again! Very frustrating.